# Before deleting an entity, deleting its parent reference(s), if any

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

It is essential to delete an entity from its parent list and the parent from the entity itself before the entity is deleted.

Example (CMT in an EJB) one-to-many from State to City :

```
public boolean delete(City city) { // Detached instance.
    City managedCity = entityManager.contains(city) ? city : entityManager.merge(city);
    managedCity.getState().getCityList().remove(managedCity);
    managedCity.setState(null);
    entityManager.remove(managedCity);
    return true;
}
```

The statement `managedCity.setState(null);` sets the entity's parent to `null`. Since it is a managed entity, any changes made to the entity will hit the underlying database. Accordingly, an `UPDATE` statement will be generated and `state_id` in the database table will be set to `null`.

```sql
UPDATE db.city SET state_id = ?, row_version = ? WHERE ((city_id = ?) AND (row_version = ?))
bind => [null, 2, 10, 1]
```

This is quite undesired. In addition to issuing an addition `UPDATE` statement, it attempts to set `state_id` in the database table to `null` which will cause problems, if a `NOT NULL` database constraint is enforced against the corresponding column in the database table.

How to correctly remove entity's parent before deleting the entity itself or it is not even required to delete (setting it to `null`) the parent before deleting the entity (it would cause problems in some cases. The answer should therefore be, *No*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have a NOT NULL constraint and a bidirectional association is better to propagate the change from the parent side:

```
public boolean delete(City city) { // Detached instance.
    City managedCity = entityManager.contains(city) ? city : entityManager.merge(city);
    managedCity.getState().getCityList().remove(managedCity);
    return true;
}
```

and make sure you cascade the REMOVE operation from Parent to Child:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

Setting the parent association to null only works when you have a NULL FK.

Comment: So, I assume that breaking a link (relationship) from either side of the relationship is sufficient i.e. either remove the entity from the list on the inverse side of the relationship or set the entity's parent itself to `null` (in case of a null foreign foreign). Both are not required. Is it?

Comment: Setting both sides is a requirement when the association is created. When breaking it you are better of cascading from Parent to Child. In a unidirectional mant-to-one association you just remove the Child. In a bidirectional association only cascading can address NOT NULL FKs as without it, if you only break one side you could get the Child reattached after delete.

Answer (score 1):

You need not delete city from state list.

```
 public boolean delete(City city) { // Detached instance.
    City managedCity = entityManager.contains(city) ? city :    entityManager.merge(city);
    //managedCity.getState().getCityList().remove(managedCity);
    //managedCity.setState(null);
    entityManager.remove(managedCity);
    return true;
```

}

you can delete all the cities when state is removed

```
class State {
 ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, ...)
  private List<City> cityList;
 ...
}
```

Comment: I also thought so. But are you sure about not setting the parent reference (`managedCity.setState(null);`)  to `null` before the entity itself is deleted? I have been reading through some places where it is highly recommended. (Removing the entity (`City`) from its parent's list, on the other hand, will be needed because only a `City` is being deleted (not its parent `State`) i.e `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` is sitting on the inverse side of the relationship which is not being deleted).